# Django modelSerializer form.is_valid() is true when values are empty

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-templates

When I run `form.is_valid()` it returns true except for branches_count and employee_count. When I run `form.save()` it returns key errors

serializers.py

```
class GeneralInformationFormSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Business
        fields = ['location', 'date_founded', 'employee_count', 'branches_count', 'business_premises']

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        return update_business_details(instance, validated_data)
```

This is models.py

```
class Business(SyncedBusinessModel):
    location = models.TextField(blank=True)
    employee_count = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    branches_count = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    business_premises = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, choices=BUSINESS_PREMISES_CHOICES)
    date_founded = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "businesses"
```

Answer (score 0):

My model fields were having blank=True which meant that the validation would pass for blank values. Since I didn't want to make the model fields compulsory but wanted this particular serializer to demand them for the other app, I add the extra_kwargs field to the serializer and that fixed the issue

```
class GeneralInformationFormSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Business
        fields = ['location', 'date_founded', 'employee_count', 'branches_count', 'business_premises']
        # Ensure these values are availed and empty strings
        extra_kwargs = {
            'location': {'required': True, 'allow_blank': False},
            'date_founded': {'required': True},
            'business_premises': {'required': True, 'allow_blank': False}
        }
```